# do $(x+1)^2$ , $(x+2)^2$ , $(x+3)^2$ span all the polynomials to the power of two or less?

Tags: linear-algebra

The subject of span and linear independence is still new to me and im unsure if what I did is considered true or not. 
what I did was, I put all of the coeffecients of the polynomials in a matrix, and reached this echelon form: \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&2&3 \\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix} which means that the polynomials are all independent so I can write all the polynomials up to the power of 2 as a linear combination of these three polynomials. 
 Is this the way to proof it? are the steps true? 
 am I supposed to do something with what i got after reaching this matrix? 
The second questions is asking if the polynomials: $x^3$, $(x+1)^3$, $(x+2)^3$, $(x+3)^3$ span all the polynomials of power to the power of 3 and less. will it be solved the same way? or im missing something that makes it easier?

 any tips or corrections or answers are really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is all correct and a perfectly valid way of approaching the problem, perhaps even the easiest approach conceptually.

Comment: There is something that may help (though not sure if you've seen it yet). If you put in your coefficients in the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\1&4&4\\1&6&9\end{bmatrix}$ and then you divide the columns by the binomial coefficients (here by ${2\choose 0}, {2\choose 1}, {2\choose 2}$, you get one *Vandermonde matrix* $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&4\\1&3&9\end{bmatrix}$, which is regular in this case because the coefficients $1,2,3$ are all different - thus its rows are linearly independent. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was just suspicious that im missing something and thought that I need to prove that if they are independent then they span it, but seems like showing that they're linearly independent is enough to show that they span every polynomial to the power of two?

Comment: You are implicitly using the theorems such as (a) every vector space has a basis, and every basis of a vector space has the same cardinality, and (b) every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis. Thus, your linearly-independent set of polynomials can be extended to the basis of all polynomial of degree $\le 2$, but as this is a $3$-dimensional space (a basis is $1,x,x^2$), then this extension is trivial and your linearly independent set is already a basis. Thus, it spans all of your vector space. The proof may differ slightly depending on the definitions/theorems you've covered.

Comment: (Cont'd) At some level of knowledge it is assumed that these steps are trivial and so is acceptable to provide a proof without explicitly calling them out - but I don't know if this is the case with you.

Comment: @StinkingBishop first of all thanks for your explanation, it really helps understand why this is true, This question is intended to be solved without knowing what a basis or dimension is, does showing that I can reach $1,x,x^2$ with my three polynomials proof that they span all polynomials of degree $\le$ 2?

Comment: Sure, that would be enough. If $1,x,x^2$ are linear combinations of $(x+1)^2,(x+2)^2,(x+3)^2$, then all polynomials of degree $\le 2$ will also be linear combinations of those. I am not sure, however, whether solving it for $1,x,x^2$ is any easier than solving it for a generic polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$. - you pretty much end up with a system of equations $\alpha(x+1)^2+\beta(x+2)^2+\gamma(x+3)^2=a+bx+cx^2$ i.e. $\begin{array}{rcl}\alpha+4\beta+9\gamma=a\\2\alpha+4\beta+6\gamma=b\\\alpha+\beta+\gamma=c\end{array}$ which as a matrix has (almost) the same matrix you've dealt with already.

Comment: @StinkingBishop What I thought about is using the coefficients that I ended up with from the echelon form of the matrix, for example to get $x^2$ I would take  $1*(x^2 +2x+1)-1(2x+3)+1(2)=x^2$, is this correct? I can take the coefficients back after I finished with the matrix row deduction? sorry if these are some obvious questions, just trying to make sure